# Why is flexsurvreg failing in this painfully simple case?

Tags: r, initialization, survival-analysis, convergence

Behold the painfully simple case and the error(s). Comments inline.

```r
library(flexsurv)
#> Loading required package: survival
library(tidyverse)
library(magrittr)
#> 
#> Attaching package: 'magrittr'
#> The following object is masked from 'package:purrr':
#> 
#>     set_names
#> The following object is masked from 'package:tidyr':
#> 
#>     extract

set.seed(2019)

train_data <- tribble(
  ~wait_time,        ~called_yet, ~time_queued,
   131.282999992371, 0,           1570733365.28,
   358.296000003815, 1,           1570733421.187,
  1352.13999986649,  1,           1570733540.923,
  1761.61400008202,  0,           1570733941.343,
  1208.25300002098,  0,           1570734327.11,
   522.296999931335, 1,           1570734376.953,
   241.75,           0,           1570734659.44,
   143.156999826431, 0,           1570734809.673,
  1202.79999995232,  1,           1570734942.907,
   614.640000104904, 1,           1570735526.567
)

# Base survival works fine!
survival_model <- survreg(Surv(wait_time, called_yet) ~ time_queued, 
                          data = train_data,
                          dist = "weibull")

survival_model
#> Call:
#> survreg(formula = Surv(wait_time, called_yet) ~ time_queued, 
#>     data = train_data, dist = "weibull")
#> 
#> Coefficients:
#>   (Intercept)   time_queued 
#>  4.533765e+05 -2.886352e-04 
#> 
#> Scale= 0.518221 
#> 
#> Loglik(model)= -40.2   Loglik(intercept only)= -40.5
#>  Chisq= 0.5 on 1 degrees of freedom, p= 0.48 
#> n= 10

# flexsurvreg can't even get a valid initializer for time_queued, even though
# the doc says it takes the mean of the data
flexsurv_model <- flexsurvreg(Surv(wait_time, called_yet) ~ time_queued,
                              data = train_data,
                              dist = "weibull")
#> Error in flexsurvreg(Surv(wait_time, called_yet) ~ time_queued, data = train_data, : Initial value for parameter 2 out of range

# Maybe the low variance of the predictor here is the problem? So let's up the
# variance just to see
train_data %<>% mutate_at("time_queued", subtract, 1.57073e9)

train_data
#> # A tibble: 10 x 3
#>    wait_time called_yet time_queued
#>        <dbl>      <dbl>       <dbl>
#>  1      131.          0       3365.
#>  2      358.          1       3421.
#>  3     1352.          1       3541.
#>  4     1762.          0       3941.
#>  5     1208.          0       4327.
#>  6      522.          1       4377.
#>  7      242.          0       4659.
#>  8      143.          0       4810.
#>  9     1203.          1       4943.
#> 10      615.          1       5527.

# Now it initializes, so that's different... but now it won't converge!
flexsurv_model <- flexsurvreg(Surv(wait_time, called_yet) ~ time_queued,
                              data = train_data,
                              dist = "weibull")
#> Warning in flexsurvreg(Surv(wait_time, called_yet) ~ time_queued, data
#> = train_data, : Optimisation has probably not converged to the maximum
#> likelihood - Hessian is not positive definite.
```

<sup>Created on 2019-10-19 by the [reprex package](https://reprex.tidyverse.org) (v0.3.0)</sup>

I mainly wanted to use `flexsurv` for its better plotting options and more standard shape & scale definitions - and the ancillary parameters are very attractive too - but now I'm mainly just wondering if I'm doing something really wrong, and `flexsurv` is trying to tell me not to trust my base `survival` model either.

Comment: Try to rescale your `time_queued` variable, using for example `train_data$time_queued <- scale(train_data$time_queued)`

Comment: Well I rescaled it from 0 to 1 (using `train_data %<>% mutate_at("time_queued", rescale, c(0, 1))`), and that did indeed work, or seem to. `flexsurvreg` converged with no issues. I see *nothing* in the documentation about value rescaling being necessary or even recommend - and its survival data, these are going to be time values, often in seconds, over many years! Well, anyway, is the moral of the story that I really do just need to deal with the rescaling and then the later unscaling in order to get interpretable results, if I want to use flexsurv? Because... now I don't. lol

Comment: You don't' need rescaling. You can simply center your variable using `train_data$time_queued <- scale(train_data$time_queued, scale=F)`. One of the main goals of standardizing/centering features is to help convergence of the technique used for optimization. See for example: https://www.cnblogs.com/quinn-yann/p/9808247.html

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Marco Sandri pointed out that recentering fixes it; however, recentering without rescaling only guarantees initialization, and still results in no convergence if the variance is very large. I'm considering this a bug since `survival` has no problem with the exact same model with the exact same values. Created an issue [here](https://github.com/chjackson/flexsurv-dev/issues/67).